# Why can't I put a float into a ptr of any type without any kind of conversion going on?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I'm currently writing a runtime for my compiler project and I want general and easy to use struct for encoding different types (the source language is scheme).

My current approach is:

```
struct SObj {
    SType type;
    uint64_t *value;
};
```

Pointer are always 64 or 32 bit wide, so shouldn't it be possible to literally put a float into my value? Then, if I want the actual value of the float, I just take the raw bytes and interprete them as a float.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are trying to implement a "tagged union" - which is usually done using a `union` as the name implies

Comment: Attempting to defeat C++'s type-safety always ends in tears. Use `std::variant` instead.

Comment: What you want is `std::variant` or `std::any`.  C++ does not like type punning and makes most ways you could do that undefined behavior.

Comment: "Pointer are always 64 or 32 bit wide" says who?

Comment: I am afraid you do not have enough knowledge yet to write a compiler on C++. There are safer and at least not less efficient ways to do it without ugly and unsafe type conversions.

Comment: C and C++ are incredibly different here. Pick one language only, please. Since C++ answers are already posted, I'll remove the C tag.

Comment: I'm not writing a compiler on C++. I'm writing a scheme runtime on C++, that's a huge difference. The implementing language is OCaml.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really.

When you write C++ you're programming an abstraction. You're *describing a program*. Contrary to popular belief, it's not "all just bytes".

Compilers are complex. They can, and will, assume that you follow the rules, and use that assumption to produce the most efficient "actual" code (read: machine code) possible.

One of those rules is that a `uint64_t*` is a pointer that points to a `uint64_t`. When you chuck arbitrary bits into there — whether they are identical to the bits that form a valid `float`, or something else — it is no longer a valid pointer, and simply evaluating it has undefined behaviour.

There are language facilities that can do what you want, like `union`. But you have to be careful not to violate aliasing rules. You'd store a flag (presumably, that's what your `type` is) that tells you which `union` member you're using. Make life easier and have a `std::variant` instead, which does all this for you.

That being said, you *can* `std::memcpy`/`std::copy` bits in and copy bits out, in say a `uint64_t` as long as they are a valid representation of the type you've chosen on your system. Just don't expect `reinterpret_cast` to be valid: it won't be.

Answer (score 2):

> Pointer are always 64 or 32 bit wide

No.

> so shouldn't it be possible to literally put a float into my value?

Yes, that is possible, although that would be very strongly advised against. C++ has many, many other facilities so you do not have to resort such things yourself. Anyway, you can interpret the bytes inside a pointer as another type. Like this:

```
static_assert(sizeof(float*) >= sizeof(float));
static_assert(std::is_pod<float>::value == true); // overdramatic

float *ptr; // just allocate sizeof(float*) bytes on stack

float a = 5;
// use the memory of the pointer to store float value
std::memcpy(&ptr, &a, sizeof(float));

float b;
std::memcpy(&b, &ptr, sizeof(float));

a == b; // true
```